# Interrupt that loads Bitmap and plays a SID file is NOT returning to main program - (6510 ASM, CBM Prog Studio)

Tags: assembly, 6502, c64, 6510

I have been trying to load a bitmap to the screen and play a sid file at the same time using an IRQ interrupt. I have it working, the Bitmap displays great, and the SID file plays wonderfully, but that's it. I want to be able to move on to the next sequence of my program either with a timer or a press of the space bar. But the entire program has frozen at the loop which checks for the timer, or in the example, I am providing the press of the space bar, but nothing happens.

When looking at the debugger (I use the visual debugger C64 65XE NES Debugger v0.64.58.4) I can see that the only area of activity is the memory where the Sid file is located $6000 onwards. It appears that I am missing something super obvious here, but not a single tutorial has the answer. I have tried to isolate the issue by removing the bitmap, but the same thing happens, so it must be in the interrupt section of the code, perhaps I'm using SEI or CEI incorrectly, I don't know!? I have tried other sid files and used different memory locations but nothing is working.

Here is the code...

```
; 10 SYS (2064)

*=$0801

    BYTE    $0E, $08, $0A, $00, $9E, $20, $28,  $32, $30, $36, $34, $29, $00, $00, $00

    ;Assign labels to memory
chapter_no = $1000
timer = $1001

    ;C64 Kernal Instructions used in this simulation
print_line = $AB1E
plot = $FFF0
chrout = $FFD2

C_Raster_Line = $d012


*=$0810  

play_music
    
    ;Initiate the music. This is done but putting the value 00 into the x- and 
    ;y-registers, and call the subroutine that resets the SID-chip. The properties 
    ;in the SID file stated that the init routine for the music is at $6000
    lda #$00
    tax
    tay
    jsr $6000
    
    ;Turn off the interrupts
    sei 

    lda #$7f
    sta $dc0d
    sta $dd0d
    lda #$01
    sta $d01a
    lda #$1b
    ldx #$08
    ldy #$14
    sta $d011
    stx $d016
    sty $d018
    lda #<irq
    ldx #>irq
    ldy #$7e
    sta $0314
    stx $0315
    sty $d012
    lda $dc0d
    lda $dd0d
    asl $d019

    cli
    
    lda #$00   ; enable CIA I and CIA II interrupts
    sta $dc0d
    sta $dd0d

    lda #$10   ; enable VIC interrupts
    sta $d011

    lda #$01   ; enable IRQ interrupts
    sta $d01a

start_BitmapLoader  
    ;Set the chapter to...
    ;CHAPTER ONE!
    lda #01
    sta chapter_no

    lda #147
    jsr chrout
    

chapter_1
    clc
    lda #$00
    ldx #00
    ldy #00

    ;Load the bitmap to screen
    lda $4710
    sta $d020
    sta $d021
    ldx #$00

loaddccimage
    lda $3f40,x
    sta $0400,x
    lda $4040,x
    sta $0500,x
    lda $4140,x
    sta $0600,x
    lda $4240,x
    sta $0700,x
    lda $4328,x
    sta $d800,x
    lda $4428,x
    sta $d900,x
    lda $4528,x
    sta $da00,x
    lda $4628,x
    sta $db00,x
    inx
    bne loaddccimage

    lda #$3b
    sta $d011
    lda #$18
    sta $d016
    lda #$18
    sta $d018


start_screen_jmp
    
    ; Check for space bar input
    jsr $FFE4      ; C64 Kernal GETIN routine
    cmp #$20       ; Check if input is space bar
    bne start_screen_jmp ; If not space bar, continue infinite loop
    
    ; If space bar pressed, clear screen and switch to character mode
    jsr $FFE4      ; Clear keyboard buffer
    lda #$93       ; C64 Kernal CLRSCR routine
    jsr $E544
    lda #$0C       ; Switch to character mode
    sta $D011
    lda #$00
    sta $D016
    lda #$00
    sta $D018

    ;Stop the music
    lda #$00
    tax
    tay
    jsr $6000

    
start_screen_jmp2      
    ;Loop forever and ever
    jmp start_screen_jmp2



*=$1ffe    
    incbin "MainBmp.prg"

irq      

    jsr $6003
    asl $d019
    jmp $ea81


    ; music code and data 
*=$6000
music_player
incbin "future60.sid", $7e
```

Comment: `jmp $ea81` returns from the interrupt without doing any of the usual stuff which includes checking keyboard that the `ffe4` routine depends on. Try `jmp $ea31` instead or store whatever the original interrupt was and jump there.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to end interrupts on a Commodore 64.

1. `jmp $ea31` is the standard way to run your code first then continue with kernel service routine.
2. `jmp $ea81` works faster. It just put the register values from stack and ends the interrupt. It did no else. If you choose this option you can call SCNKEY manually to update the keyboard buffer.
3. Instead of relaying to kernal you can do all manually. i.e.:

```
PLA
TAY
PLA
TAX
PLA
RTI
```

### Solution

As you are using `jmp $ea81` you have two options. Either call SCNKEY first:

```
; Check for space bar input
    jsr $ea87      ; Call SCNKEY
    jsr $FFE4      ; C64 Kernal GETIN routine
    cmp #$20       ; Check if input is space bar
    bne start_screen_jmp ; If not space bar, continue infinite loop
```

or use your own keyboard scan

```
; Check for space bar
    lda $dc01      ; Check Data Port B
    cmp #$ef       ; For space bar
    bne start_scree_jmp ; If not space bar, continue infinite loop
```

Another solution would be to use `jmp $ea31` instead of `jmp $ea81`.